# Wrong way to acess each checkbox in listView multichoice?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview, parent-child

I have a listView multichoice, Each row of list have a checkbox. And I have an arrayList with the positions of list that i want checked on checkbox. But something is wrong because don't work...

Here is my code
     listViewSocios->ListView
     alPositionsOnList -> Array list

```
 CheckBox checkedBox;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<SessaoQuotaEdit.alPositionsOnList.size() ; i++){
        checkedBox = (CheckBox)((View)listViewSocios.getChildAt((Integer) SessaoQuotaEdit.alPositionsOnList.get(i))).findViewById(android.R.id.checkbox);
        checkedBox.setChecked(true);
    }
```

Any Idea?

Give an error in this line

```
    checkedBox = (CheckBox)((View)listViewSocios.getChildAt((Integer) SessaoQuotaEdit.alPositionsOnList.get(i))).findViewById(android.R.id.checkbox);
```

Comment: So you have a multiple choice ListView and want to check off the rows that are stored in `alPositionsOnList`? How do you define `alPositionsOnList` is it `List<Integer>`?

Comment: Hello Sam. yes is ArrayList<Integer>alPositionsOnList = new ArrayList(); I update for checkedBox = (CheckBox)((View)listViewSocios.getChildAt( SessaoQuotaEdit.alPositionsOnList.get(i))).findViewById(android.R.id.checkbox); remove the cast but, not work....

Comment: What is the precise exception? can you post that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) : `ListView` has this method `setItemChecked(int position, boolean value)`.

Comment: Wingman work's fine thank you, i don't remember that way. However you know what's wrong with my older code? I supose that it should work....

Comment: Without knowing what error you get, it's hard to tell but it's quite possible you're not locating the checkbox correctly. Try hard-coding a `1` in there as an index and see if you can actually retrieve the checkbox or if you're getting a null/casting exception

Comment: @RicardoFilipe  The approach you took is not safe. First,You should avoid casting, Only if you are 100% sure that list items are what you think they are, and that's only possible when you provided those item Views yourself from your own custom adapter. Also ListView's support multiple kind of item views in same list , plus header and footer views.

Comment: Thanks to all for your time and help :)